# Regex n character to n character

Tags: regex, character, regular-language

***7/25/2015 5:45:40 AM*** ... I am trying to return "**5:45:40 AM**" the time from this string using regex, I just learned about this abstract language 15 minutes ago. I am having a really difficult time. I know how to get to the beginning of the first to nth characters and last nth characters but, not n to n characters. Is that even possible? You would think its something like .({11}, .{20}$)
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going by character count would be incorrect in this situation, because the length of the date portion is variable: `8/1/2015` is only 8 characters long, while `12/12/2015` is ten characters long.

You would be better off matching `\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2} (AM|PM)` to capture the time portion of the string.

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/aB3rD0/2)

Comment: Thank you!!!, I would have never figured that out... I'll keep watch tuts and practicing.

Comment: I did, however I'm a n@@b and my opinion doesn't count... :(, well actually it did, I was just being a complete n@@b and did not click the check mark.... :/ silly me

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the number of characters since it might change (e.g., 12/25/2015 has 1 additional character). You can use this pattern with capture groups:

```
\d+\/\d+\/\d+\s(\d+:\d+:\d+\s(AM|PM))
```

The first capture will match the substring you need (5:45:40 AM)

Check out this [example](https://regex101.com/r/uL6rX1/1)